# Binding a NOT query expression in UI checkbox widget?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have to filter results on 3 values - "done", "pending" and 3rd option that would find anything that is not "done" or "pending" in @datasource.item.Type

Is it possible to bind a 3rd checkbox button to show any values that are not "done or "pending" -- e.g. !(Type = :done or Type = :pending)

Here is a screenshot of what I have so far, this errors out with:

```
Cannot complete binding from nullItemName to @datasources.Data.items.length 
( Type = :done or Type = :pending). Unexpected error on binding initial 
sync write : Null item name cannot be set to null. in
FiltersDialog.Content.Dropdown1
```

[Screenshot of drop-down menu with NOT query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP8ea.png)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what you have on your UI? Maybe I can suggest something.

Comment: Typically I have always used a checkbox with a datasource parameter binding like CheckThisFieldForNullValue (boolean) and done an if statement in the datasource server query script like `if(CheckThisFieldForNullValue){query.filters.ThisField._equals = null;`. Unfortunately for dropdowns to filter by these types of categories and to include null is not really possible, because your dropdown No Selection option is also null, so in this case it would be interpreted to not apply a filter for the field.

Comment: @ Morfinismo Thank you, I added a screenshot. I'm not necessarily looking for NULL value, rather listing all @datasource.query.filters.Type who aren't "pending" or "done".

Comment: @KathyS I provided some additional suggestions to hopefully make the code better in the event that you add additional possible values for your field. Again it’s untested but conceptually speaking this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a possible solution, since this is untested however there is no guarantee that it will work.

It will require the following edits to your current bindings:

1.) Remove the names binding completely and set the nullItemName back to 'No Selection'.
2.) Change the options binding to `(@models.Data.fields.Type.possibleValues).concat('Not done or pending')`.
3.) Remove the value binding completely.
4.) Enter the following in your dropdown onValueChange event:

```
if(newValue !== null) {
  if (newValue === 'Not done or pending') {
    widget.datasource.query.filters.Type._notIn = ['done','pending'];
  } else {
    widget.datasource.query.filters.Type._equals = newValue;
  }
}
```

To provide for better future compatibility in the event that you choose to add additional possible values to the type field and to make for a more foolproof UI I would suggest the following edits and additions:

Make sure your ‘Clear’ Button includes:

```
widget.datasource.query.clearFilters();
widget.root.descendants.Dropdown1.value = null;
```

Modify your options binding to `(@models.Data.fields.Type.possibleValues).concat(‘Not ‘ + (@models.Data.fields.Type.possibleValues).join(‘ or ‘))`

Modify the onValueChange event to:

```
if(newValue !== null) {
  if(newValue === widget.options[widget.options.length - 1]) {
    widget.datasource.query.filters.Type._notIn = widget.datasource.model.fields.Type.possibleValues;
  } else {
    widget.datasource.query.filters.Type._equals = newValue;
  }
}
```

Might need minor adjustments to the new code, since I’m just typing this up from memory. Don’t actually have App Maker in front of me right now.